# MongoDB - Error connecting to 192.xx.xx.xx : Too many open files

Tags: c#, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, sharding

I've setup my mongodb (v4.2.8) sharded cluster on ubuntu 18.04 and using c#.net for my application. I have 2 mongoS in my cluster and below is my code to connect to my mongodb shard

```
public sealed class MongoDBConnection
{
private static MongoClient client1 = null;
public static MongoClient Connection1
        {
            get
            {
                if (client1 == null)
                {
                    lock (InstanceLock)
                    {
                        if (client1 == null)
                        {
                            TimeSpan connectionTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
                            MongoClientSettings settingShard = new MongoClientSettings
                            {
                                MaxConnectionPoolSize = 60000,
                                MinConnectionPoolSize = 30000,
                                ConnectTimeout = connectionTime,
                                Server = new MongoServerAddress("xxx.xxx.xx.xx", 27017)
                            };
                            client1 = new MongoClient(settingShard);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return client1;
            }
        }
}
```

this class contains all settings to my connection and below is my class to perform DB operatoins

```
public static class MongoDBOperations
{
        private static IMongoClient consDB1 = MongoDBConnection.Connection1;
        private static IMongoDatabase MyDB1 = consDB1.GetDatabase("DBEmp");
        private static IMongoCollection<EmpDetails> Mycollection1= MyDB1.GetCollection<EmpDetails>("tblEmployees");

        public static Queue<string> returnEmployeeList(int limit)
        {
            Queue<string> empQ = new Queue<string>();
            try
            {
                var filter = Builders<EmpDetails>.Filter.Eq("InfoUpdated", 0);
                var emp1 = Mycollection1.Find(filter).Limit(limit).ToList();
                if (emp1.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < emp1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var _Emp = Builders<EmpDetails>.Filter.Eq("EmailAddress", emp1[i].EmailAddress);
                        var UpdateDef = Builders<EmpDetails>.Update.Set(s => s.InfoUpdated, 1).Set(s => s.InfoUpdatedOn, DateTime.Now.Date);
                        var result = Mycollection1.UpdateManyAsync(_Emp, UpdateDef);
                        empQ.Enqueue(emp[i].EmailAddress.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.WriteLine("No Emp found to update : ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in Getting emp from DB: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return empQ;
        }
}
```

so what I am actually doing is, I am returning a queue from my class and do some stuff on that list. As soon as the records are fetched from database, I update there status "InfoUpdated" to 1 so they are not picked agian.

I am doing this in my multithreaded application and below is the code for that

```
class Program
{
   static Dictionary<string, Queue<string>> Qs = new Dictionary<string, Queue<string>>();
   static int elementsInQueue = 100;
   static int totalQueues = 200;
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      new Program().FillUpQueuesOnStart();
   }
   void FillUpQueuesOnStart()
   {
      for (int i = 1; i <= totalQueues; i++)
      {
         if (!Qs.ContainsKey("q" + i))
            Qs.Add("q" + i, new Queue<string>());
         Qs["q" + i] = MongoDBOperations.returnEmployeeList(elementsInQueue);
         Console.WriteLine("q" + i + " filled on start");
      }
   }
}
```

when I run my program, it works fine initially and fills up to 35 to 30 queues, but then gives the following error

```
Error connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017 :: caused by :: Too many open files
```

where xxx.xxx.xx.xxx is the IP of one of my shards. I see this error on one of my mongoS' terminal in my cluster. I've searched a lot on this to no help. I even changed the ulimit -n in all of my nodes in my cluster, still to no luck.
Any help would really be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many shards?  Apparently you are hitting either an OS limit or a Mongo limit.

Comment: `Too many open files` is a system limit.  Note that every open network connection also counts as an open file handle.  What does `ulimit` or `/proc/<pic>/limits` show for the max open files?

Comment: @Rick James, I've 3 shards with one replica member

Comment: @Joe - here are the results for ulimit

serverdb-3@serverdb3:~$ ulimit
unlimited

Comment: I even followed the steps described on https://www.linuxtechi.com/set-ulimit-file-descriptors-limit-linux-servers/ still to no luck :(